# paint() method not Accepting updated variables in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to draw cars that get generated into an `ArrayList` called `Cars` inside the  `tryCar()` method it prints the proper size when I call `System.out.println(Cars.size());` but once I try to draw it inside the `paint()` method it does not recognize it.
Here is my code.
`r` is a `Random()` from `java.util.Random`

```
public void Update(){
    if(r.nextInt(100)>85){
        tryCar();
    }
}

void tryCar(){
    if(r.nextBoolean()){
        Car c = new Car(r.nextInt(2), r.nextInt(6)+6, r.nextBoolean());
        Cars.add(c);
        cars++;
        System.out.println(Cars.size());
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Road.drawLvl(g);
    System.out.println(Cars.size());
    g.fillRect(p1.X,p1.Y,p1.W,p1.H);
    for(int i = 0; i<Cars.size(); i++){ 
        System.out.println("s");
        Car c = (Car) Cars.get(i);
        g.setColor(new Color((r.nextInt(2)*255),(r.nextInt(2)*255),(r.nextInt(2)*255)));
        g.fillRect(c.X,c.Y,c.W,c.H);
    }
}
```

Here is the entire class:

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int CARS = 20;
int cars = 0;
ArrayList Cars = new ArrayList();
Player p1 = new Player(20,20);
Environment Road = new Environment(1);
Random r = new Random();
public void Update(){
    System.out.println("c");
    if(r.nextInt(100)>85){
        System.out.println("e");
        tryCar();
    }
    p1.Move(Main.c);
}
void tryCar(){
    if(r.nextBoolean()){
        System.out.println("v");
        Car c = new Car(r.nextInt(2), r.nextInt(6)+6, r.nextBoolean());
        Cars.add(c);
        cars++;
            System.out.println(Cars.size());
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Road.drawLvl(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
    //      System.out.println(p1.X);
    System.out.println(Cars.size());
    g.fillRect(p1.X,p1.Y,p1.W,p1.H);
    for(int i = 0; i<Cars.size(); i++){ 
        System.out.println("s");
        Car c = (Car) Cars.get(i);
        g.setColor(new Color((r.nextInt(2)*255),(r.nextInt(2)*255),(r.nextInt(2)*255)));
        g.fillRect(c.X,c.Y,c.W,c.H);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `"but once I try to draw it inside the print() method it does not recognize it."` -- What `print()` method?? And don't draw directly inside of a JFrame. Instead read the tut's on drawing in Swing.

Comment: sorry, I meant `paint`, will fix

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Even if I'm drawing on something else, I need to use Swing's `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods, correct?

Comment: Define "it doesn't recognize it". What happens, and when, and what do you expect instead. Also please respect the Java naming conventions: variables and methods start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @JBNizet What happens is that the car will be added to the `ArrayList` and is recognized when I call `System.out.println(Cars.size());` inside the `tryCar()` method, but when I then call the same line inside of paint (as well as the for loop there), `Cars.size()` comes up as `0`. I instead thought that a rectangle would be painted at the car's location

Comment: Then either you're not showing us the real code, or some method changes the list of cars before paint() is called.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added the entire Class un-edited.

Comment: Don't call setVisible or setBackground front within the paint method, this could setup a recursive call which will constantly call paint until your CPU is running at 100%

Comment: Rewrite a self-contained example, that we can simply copy and paste, compile and run. And make sure this example uses correct naming. You have three variables called CARS, cars and Cars. Have you thought adding one named cArs and one named CaRs?

Comment: How is update called? How is the component repainted?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Here is the `Main` Class which is used to call it.
http://pastebin.com/RmpH0gBX
@JBNizet I will now write a self contained copy

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the fact that Swing image rally not thread safe, that means that in most cases, any updates to the UI should be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

For this, generally, `javax.swing.Timer` is preferred mechanism for scheduling regular call backs that need to modify the state of the UI

Also, repainting the main window may not be enough to cause the child components to repaint.

In your linked code example, you could, call `repaint` from your `update` method, the danger here is that you could be making modifications to the state while the component is been painted, causing inconsistencies in the output.

This is why I'd recommend using a `javax.swing.Timer` instead, as it would allow you to update the state within the context of the EDT (which is also responsible for performing paint updates), meaning its (near) impossible for the state to be update and painted at the same time

As a general rule, Swing components should override `paintComponent` to perform custom painting

Answer (score -1):

The Car is added to the Cars when through the `Update` method. If, in the `paint`, the array is empty it is because no Car has been added to Cars. So, just make sure the `Update` method is being called otherwise the array will always be empty - unless you modify the array directly and not via `Update`.

Comment: -1, `Try adding a call to Update inside of paint` the painting method should NOT update its own state, only paint its state.

Comment: This worked, but I feel slightly Icky calling Update from pain, is there some way to call from another class and still make sure it updates? if you check above you can see how I currently update the class in my Main.java

Comment: Do not call Update from paint. That was just an hyperbole indicating that Update should be called.